# wxPython import error

Tags: python, wxpython, importerror, python-import

I'm having trouble figuring out an error message in Python.

yesterday, I've installed python using the latest EPD package, and wxPython2.9 using the wxPython2.9-osx-cocoa-py2.7 package for Mac OS.
I then added wx to my PYTHONPATH.

```
export WXDIR=/usr/local/lib/wxPython-2.9.1.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.9.1-osx_cocoa
export PYTHONPATH=$WXDIR
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$WXDIR/tools
```

but when I try to run stuff I get this error:

```
In [14]: import matplotlib.pyplot
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

/Users/imrisofer/Documents/third/hddm-read-only/hddm/<ipython console> in <module>()

/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in <module>()
     93 
     94 from matplotlib.backends import pylab_setup
---> 95 new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, show = pylab_setup()
     96 
     97 @docstring.copy_dedent(Artist.findobj)

/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py in pylab_setup()
     23         backend_name = 'matplotlib.backends.%s'%backend_name.lower()
     24     backend_mod = __import__(backend_name,
---> 25                              globals(),locals(),[backend_name])
     26 
     27     # Things we pull in from all backends


/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_wxagg.py in <module>()
     21 
     22 from backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
---> 23 import backend_wx    # already uses wxversion.ensureMinimal('2.8')
     24 from backend_wx import FigureManager, FigureManagerWx, FigureCanvasWx, \
     25     FigureFrameWx, DEBUG_MSG, NavigationToolbar2Wx, error_msg_wx, \

/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_wx.py in <module>()
     43         import wxversion
     44     except ImportError:
---> 45         raise ImportError(missingwx)
     46 
     47     # Some early versions of wxversion lack AlreadyImportedError.


ImportError: Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxPython >=2.8
```

I can successfully import wx, so I don't no what's the problem.
Am I missing anything in the PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score 15):

In Ubuntu 12.04, this problem can be solved by running the command

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62
```

I realize this may not be useful here, but I wanted to document it somewhere on teh interwebz so I can find it when I run into this problem again myself which will undoubtedly happen.

Comment: problem encountered on 12.04 with EPD 7.3 and solved by the above. well done @Chad

Comment: I've actually switched to Fedora and encountered similar problems with libpng...  The EPD error description consistently does a good job of explaining what package (or lack of package) is causing the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10, Canopy 1.2, and PyCharm 3.0.2. When trying to use matlablib, it always complains "Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxPython >=2.8".Pretty sure that I'm using wxPython 2.8. Then I tried all the methods described in this page, but neither of them works for me.

It turns out that it can be solved by modifying matplotlibrc file. There is a line:

> backend : WXAgg

In fact we can change the backend to whatever we like, and I change it to TKAgg, which works just fine for me.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this solution? I also have Ubuntu 13.10 and have the error:
`ImportError: Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxPython >=2.8`.  
According to Canopy I have wxPython 2.8.10.1-3 installed.
**Note:** The code I was executing was working when I had the same version of Enthought installed on Ubuntu 12.04.
**Note:** I also found this support message about the error: https://support.enthought.com/entries/22601196-wxPython

Comment: Ah do you mean the following file: `/home/YOU/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc`? This appears to be working so far. Are there any other issues I might experience due to switching the backend?

Comment: Hi alexgophermix, I haven't experienced other issues so far.

Answer (score 4):

Select your wx version before importing any wx modules

`import wxversion`
`wxversion.select('2.8')`

The above code should come before `import wx`

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me on a Windows x64 installation that did not install wxversion.py in the site-packages directory (c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages by default).

You can get a copy of wxversion.py from the WX svn repository:
http://svn.wxwidgets.org/viewvc/wx/wxPython/trunk/wxversion/wxversion.py?content-type=text%2Fplain&view=co

Answer (score 2):

this link helped me
https://support.enthought.com/entries/22601196-wxPython-2-8-and-2-9

Here's how I fixed the problem, which I hope will be useful for others in future

1. In Terminal: gedit Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc
2. Edit the line "backend      : WXAgg" into "backend      : QtAgg"
3. Save and exit

Comment: Yeap, it seems that QtAgg backend for matplotlib exists

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this myself. One potential cause of this (quite unhelpful) error message is if you installed `wx` as a single-version installation (`INSTALL_MULTIVERSION=0` when running `setup.py`). In this case, the module `wxversion` does not get built (or installed) and as such matplotlib incorrectly assumes that all of `wx` is missing.

This currently is the default setting in installations by the [homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) version of wxWidgets (`wxmac`) with the option `--python`.

In your case (albeit a year and a half late), you'd need to ensure that `wxversion.py` exists within `/usr/local/lib/wxPython-2.9.1.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`. If it doesn't, you'd need to recompile wx with the above flag set. Otherwise you just need to set your `$PYTHONPATH` such that it includes the base site-packages directory, too:

```
export WXDIR=/usr/local/lib/wxPython-2.9.1.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages
export PYTHONPATH=$WXDIR:$WXDIR/wx-2.9.1-osx_cocoa:$WXDIR/wx-2.9.1-osx_cocoa/tools
```

Comment: To have homebrew install wxpython with the multiversion support turned on . You can run command brew edit wxwidgets . Then edit the line where it says INSTALL_MULTIVERSION=0 to INSTALL_MULTIVERSION=1 . Then save the recipe and proceed with the install.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved with this:

```
defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by setting the backend to MacOSX in ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc:

backend : MacOSX

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this on Windows by looking in the site packages folder in the python library. In there, there should be another folder titled site-packages. In this subfolder, there is the wxversion library. If you copy this library into the Lib folder in python, this import error should be averted.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxtools
```

Install it. Worked for me.