# Installing wxPython on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wxpython, installation, debian, ubuntu-12.04

**The Issue:** I am having trouble installing wxPython on Ubuntu 12.04. *I would like to find a simple, straightforward way of doing this.*

**What I've Done So Far:** The most relevant instructions that I have been able to find so far can be found here: http://wiki.wxpython.org/InstallingOnUbuntuOrDebian

The issue with these instructions is that there is no choice available for Precise 12.04. The most up-to-date distro shown is Natty 11.4. From what I can find, the proper way to do this is to manually build debian packages, which is explained here: http://wiki.wxpython.org/BuildingDebianPackages

Upon attempting this and finally typing the command 'fakeroot debian/rules binary', I get the errors:

> debian/rules:14: /usr/share/quilt/quilt.make: No such file or directory
>   pyversions: missing X(S)-Python-Version in control file, fall back to debian/pyversions
>   pyversions: missing debian/pyversions file, fall back to supported versions
>   make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/share/quilt/quilt.make'.  Stop.

I cannot seem to fix this error, or find any other applicable resources that work for me. I would post more links here, but since I am new, the spam filter is blocking me from doing so.

**Conclusion: *Does someone know a simple solution to properly installing wxPython on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise?***

**Update:** I tried just simply using the apt-get command 'sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8', and I received this (which seems good):

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   python-wxgtk2.8 is already the newest version.
>   The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
>   language-pack-zh-hans yaml-cpp language-pack-kde-en language-pack-kde-zh-hans language-pack-kde-en-base language-pack-zh-hans-base language-pack-kde-zh-hans-base
>   Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 173 not upgraded.

But once I attempt to run something, ie 'python test_gui.py', I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test_gui.py", line 1, in 
>     import wx
>   ImportError: No module named wx

Comment: I have attempted to figure out how to overcome these errors, and was able to find [this resource](http://wiki.debian.org/Python/Policy), though I wasn't successful in finding any information I could use.

So, after trying all of these things, I did some more searching and I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/wxpython-users/SqybVaIi954y) and [this](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/ubuntu-installation-woes-td5714779.html) resource.

Comment: And, the only somewhat applicable Stack Overflow posts that I can find was [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121574/wxpython-import-error), but it only applies to Mac OSX and is about a separate error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Okay, so I was able to figure it out. It turned out to be a combination of things.

1. First make sure that you have Python installed
2. Install wxGTK 2.8 with the command, `sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8`
3. Run the command, `apt-get source -d wxwidgets2.8`
4. Now run, `dpkg-source -x wxwidgets2.8_2.8.12.1-6ubuntu2.dsc`
5. `cd wxwidgets2.8-2.8.12.1`
6. `cd wxPython`
7. Now run the command, `sudo python setup.py install`
8. wxPython and wxWidgets are now successfully installed!

Comment: the following dependencies are required: dpkg-dev build-essential swig python2.7-dev libwebkitgtk-dev libjpeg-dev libtiff-dev freeglut3 freeglut3-dev libgtk2.0-dev  libsdl1.2-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev -- (from: http://wiki.wxpython.org/CheckInstall)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this! FYI, the last command (for me) emitted an error: `In file included from src/helpers.cpp:16:0:
include/wx/wxPython/wxPython_int.h:19:19: fatal error: wx/wx.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`. But it appears you can safely ignore this. wxPython worked fine for me, despite the 'scary' output at the end...

Comment: Same experience as evadeflow above, but had to restart the terminal/python/etc to have it work.

Comment: If you want to install in a virtualenv (and why would you be doing anything else?) then replace step 7 with "python setup.py sdist", and you can install the resulting dist/xxx.tar.gz wherever you like using pip.

Answer (score 35):

Okay. So I have figured out a way out Just run the following command in a Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxtools wx2.8-doc wx2.8-examples wx2.8-headers wx2.8-i18n
```

And Voila! It works!

Comment: Easier than the accepted answer, which was giving me: unable to find a source package for wxwidgets2.8

Comment: This didn't work for me: Ubuntu 12.10, Python2.6. $python -c "import wx" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>, 
  File "wx/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>, 
    from wx._core import *, 
  File "wx/_core.py", line 4, in <module>, 
    import _core_, 
ImportError: No module named _core_

Answer (score 9):

`sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxtools wx2.8-i18n libwxgtk2.8-dev libgtk2.0-dev` Works for me

source:http://wiki.wxpython.org/InstallingOnUbuntuOrDebian

Answer (score 3):

You can also install it with **Pip**, but with a *slight modification* to the install command.

**From the wxPython [website](https://wxpython.org/pages/downloads/index.html):**

> Because of the differences between Linux distributions (mainly
>   different versions of the core libraries installed by default, but
>   also platform architecture and etc.) it is not possible to host binary
>   wheel files for Linux on PyPI unless they can be made to work within
>   the constraints of PEP 513 Unfortunately, attempts to pound the
>   wxPython peg into the manylinux1 hole have not been very successful.
>   Maybe manylinux2 will be a better fit. In the meantime, if you have a
>   Linux similar enough to those used to build the wheels located under
>   the wxPython Extras linux folder, then you can use them and not need
>   to build the wheels yourself.
>
> Since there are various options for distro and wx port (GTK2 or GTK3)
>   then the files can not all be located in the same folder for easy
>   access by pip. This simply just means that you'll need to drill down a
>   little further to find the URL to give to pip. For example, to get the
>   GTK3 wxPython builds for Ubuntu 16.04 (and 16.10, LinuxMint 18, and
>   probably others) you can use a pip command like this:

```
pip install -U -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-16.04 wxPython
```

Answer (score 1):

gtk3 should be install first

```
$sudo apt-get libgtk-3-dev
```

If you are facing problem to install wxpython on Python3 please use this command to install wxpython

```
$ pip install -U -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-16.04 wxPython
```

By this command you can install latest wxPython4 version.
If you are using Windows or macOS

```
$ pip install -U wxpython
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 12.04.5 I had to use all of this

```
apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxtools wx2.8-doc wx2.8-examples wx2.8-headers wx2.8-i18n python-wxversion libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0
```

Answer (score -1):

I have succeed to install wxpython follow this way (also ubuntu 12.04):

- 1. The packages and the repository meta-data are digitally signed, so you'll need to import the key into your apt's list of trusted keys in order to not get warnings about it.
- 2. Add the lines to your /etc/apt/sources.list file
- 3. Run the this command to update your local copy of the package meta-data.

  > sudo apt-get update
- 4. You can now use your favorite package selection tool to install or upgrade the wxWidgets and wxPython packages. Here's how to do it with apt-get:

  > sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxtools wx2.8-i18n

reference link:

http://wiki.wxpython.org/InstallingOnUbuntuOrDebian