# The Critical Error While Installing wxpython On Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

Having read several resources (eg [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007557/installing-wxpython-on-ubuntu-12-04) one)  on installing wxpython on Ubuntu 12.04, I muddled it all. My terminal outputs a single error upon writing, for instance, a statement `sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8`, which is required for the proper installation of the GUI. Namely, it displays `" E: The package wxpython needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.`

I  scanned all the folders that contain files connected with wxpython in order to delete them and reinstall the package. Anyway, it didn't work.

Could you please tell me what steps can be applied to resolve the problem?

Comment: Manually removing files `dpkg` had installed is a terrible idea. Your system is now hosed if it wasn't already.

Comment: Thank you, tripleee. Could you please tell me what I can undertake to fix it? The problem is that I have started deleting files after I got the error.

Comment: Not a programming topic anyway. Maybe somebody over on http://superuser.com will refrain from asking why you simply don't restore from backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when the package list is not up to date.

1) First you have to update package archive list by running following command;

```
    sudo apt-get update
```

2) Once package archive list updated, run following command;

```
    sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8
```

Further reading @ [Ubuntu Package Management from Command line using apt](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-package-management-from-command-line-using-apt-advanced-packaging-tool.html)

** However, if you have mistakenly removed/disabled “apt” repositories, it would be easier to use GUI based repository management tool to reconfigure “Software sources”.
Have a look @ [GUI-based repository management](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

Comment: The step one 1 is successfully executed. Nevertheless, the same error, which interrupts the procedure of the command, is displayed after the attempt to execute the second step.

Comment: Then you have removed or disabled some repo in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` or similar.

Comment: Dear tripleee, thank you for your reply. Would you mind telling me how I can fix that, since I am not sure I have done it intentionally? Anyway, I don't remember removing or disabling any repos.

Comment: Fortunately, the problem is fixed owing to the answer by bodhi.zazen there - 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/88371/apt-synaptic-needs-to-reinstall-package-but-cant-find-the-archive-for-it