# Installing wxpython on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, wxpython

When I try to open PlayOnLinux from the commandline, I get this error:

```
Looking for python... 2.7.8 - selected
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mainwindow.py", line 31, in <module>
    import wxversion
ImportError: No module named wxversion
```

Nearly every forum post I have found has suggested I install wxPython, then links [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/BuildingDebianPackages) or to some other wxpython wiki page. Unfortunately, the entire wxpython wiki website currently says "wxPyWiki is down for troubleshooting" right now.

I found [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007557/installing-wxpython-on-ubuntu-12-04) question, which is basically the same as mine. I tried all the lower-voted comments, and they all appear to work, but `import wx` still fails. When I tried the top-rated comment in that thread, I got to step 7 successfully, but then it says

```
In file included from scr/helpers.cpp:16:0:
include/wx/wxPython/wxPython_int.h:19:19: fatal error: wx/wx.h: No such file or directory
#include <wx/wx.h>

compilation terminated
```

If anyone has any suggestions for how I can properly install wxPython on Ubuntu, they would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: `sudo pip install wxPython` tells me it's already installed ("Requirement already satisfied") and suggests I use `--upgrade`. It's not installed, `import wx` still fails.

EDIT: `sudo apt-get install wxpython` gives the error `Unable to locate package wxpython`

EDIT: I tried `sudo apt-get install python-wxglade` and it appeared to work, but playonlinux still gives the same error and `import wx` still fails.

EDIT: I tried uninstalling and reinstalling playonlinux and python-wxversion. Both remove/install appeared successful, but I still get the same `No module named wxversion` error.

EDIT: I tried the solutions posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498834/playonlinux-wont-start) (except for reinstalling the OS). They did not work. I'd rather not reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: `sudp pip install wxPython` is how I did it ... I think you can also do `sudo apt-get install wxpython`

Comment: I've used pip before but never on this computer and apparently it's not installed. `yum -y install python-pip` gives me the error `There are no enabled repos.` When I try `sudo apt-get install wxpython` it gives me the error `Unable to locate package wxpython`. Any other suggestions?

Edit: `sudo apt-get install python-pip` worked but now `sudo pip install wxPython` tells me `Requirement already satisfied`.

Comment: You can't use pip to install wxPython except for the Phoenix version, which is still very alpha.

Answer (score 2):

Before that install gtk3

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```

If you are facing problem to install wxpython on Python3 please use this command to install wxpython

```
$ pip install -U -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-16.04 wxPython
```

By this command you can install latest wxPython4 version.
If you are using Windows or macOS

```
$ pip install -U wxpython
```

If you are using Anaconda/Conda

```
$ conda install -C anaconda wxpython
```

Comment: I needed wxPython for python3, because nowdays python2.7 seems to be deprecared with modern python libraries like tensorflow.
I got wxPython to Ubuntu 14.04 with hint of this answer

sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev && sudo pip3 install wxPython

It took some time to compile, but succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

The answer about installing "python-wxgtk2.8" is correct. But that's if you want to install 2.8, if you want 3.0 in 14.04, you can get it by following [this post](http://pygopar.com/installing-wxpython-3-on-ubuntu14-04). I have done that, and have wx 3.0 installed.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: This method doesn't work anymore for either Trusty 14.04 or Mint 17. Try this instead ([ref](https://gist.github.com/johnbeard/4d1a8e43b05bcb03e9b4))  

 `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adamwolf/kicad-trusty-backports` |

 `sudo apt-get update` |

 `sudo apt-get install libwxgtk3.0-dev python-wxgtk3.0-dev`

Answer (score 1):

All you need is:

`sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk3.0`

Comment: Didn't work for me.  Python-wxgtk3.0 successfully installed but PlayOnLinux still cannot import wxversion

Answer (score 0):

Try installing python-wxglade.It must have all necessary wx modules inside.

Comment: I used `sudo apt-get install python-wxglade` and it appeared to work, but playonlinux still gives the same error and `import wx` still fails.

Answer (score 0):

Check Synaptic for wxPython 3.x to see if you can install it that way. According to https://www.playonlinux.com/en/news.html, version 4.2.5 of PlayOnLinux supports wxPython 3. If you can't get Synaptic to find a copy of wxPython 3, then you should refer to the official build instructions found here:

- http://wxpython.org/builddoc.php

Answer (score 0):

wxPython package is named "python-wxgtk2.8" for wxWidgets 2.8
Install it: *sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8*

Comment: This answer will work unless you are trying to isntall to virtual environment/secondary python directory.

Comment: This package no longer exists and was replaced by version 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things, so I'm not sure if this is the minimum set of pre-requisites.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libwxbase3.0-dev libwxgtk3.0-dev wx-common libwebkit-dev libwxgtk-webview3.0-dev wx3.0-examples wx3.0-headers wx3.0-i18n libwxgtk-media3.0-dev
```

Then I pip installed the Phoenix version:

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade --pre -f http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ --trusted-host wxpython.org wxPython_Phoenix
```

This installs wxPython via pip, but I don't think it addresses your issue with `wxversion`.