# How to install wxPython 3.0.2.0 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: python, ubuntu, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to install wxPython from src as I need the exact version 3.0.2.0 on Ubuntu. (So, I cannot follow the suggesion in the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240143/installing-wxpython-on-ubuntu-14-04)) I downloaded the source and did ./configure, make and make install. It seems to have ended without errors with the following message.

> The installation of wxWidgets is finished.  On certain  platforms
>   (e.g. Linux) you'll now have to run ldconfig  if you installed a
>   shared library and also modify the  LD_LIBRARY_PATH (or equivalent)
>   environment variable.    wxWidgets comes with no guarantees and
>   doesn't claim  to be suitable for any purpose.

I confirmed my installation is not working by doing import wx & wx.version(). What needs to be done to complete the installation? Where should I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing ./configure, make and make install only builds and installs wxWidgets.  You also need to build wxPython using the `build-wxpython.py` script, which by default will also do the wxWidgets portion of the build for you, using known good configure flags.  See wxPython/docs/BUILD.txt in the source tarball.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if wx is in sys.pah.

You can do it with this code

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

In output must be something like that `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx`

If not, adding path to wx folder to system path should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

gtk3 should be install first

```
$sudo apt-get libgtk-3-dev
```

If you are facing problem to install wxpython on Python3 please use this command to install wxpython

```
$ pip install -U -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-16.04 wxPython
```

By this command you can install latest wxPython4 version.
If you are using Windows or macOS

```
$ pip install -U wxpython
```

Older Version you can get from this link
https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/