# [Pyo/Jackd/PulseAudio]: Jack Error: Unabel to create JACK client (CromeOS/CROUTON/Precise)

Tags: python, arm, chroot, google-chrome-os, pulseaudio

Trying to get the [PYO](http://ajaxsoundstudio.com/software/pyo/) music module to work on my Chromebook (Chroot Dev) (ARM7 processor) (Precise Penguin/ubuntu 12.04)

pyo:

```
>>>import pyo
pyo version 0.7.7 (uses single precision)
>>>pyo.Server(audio='jack').boot()
```

---

Due to the ARM processor and Precise some small modifications to the dependencies were necessary:

1] ARM changes to /proc/cpuinfo in relation to Jackd2, error:

```
FATAL: cannot locate cpu MHz in /proc/cpuinfo
```

[solution?](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/765800/workaround-for-fatal-cannot-locate-cpu-mhz-in-proc-cpuinf/) The error changed after, but not knowledgeable enough to know if for the better.

2] xwPython3.0 not available for Precise:

[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007557/installing-wxpython-on-ubuntu-12-04), shouldn't be a problem as this is UI dependency correct?

---

And to this is where the error is now:

```
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jackdmp 1.9.11
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2015 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
/usr/local/bin/jackd: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/bin/jackd: undefined symbol: jackctl_driver_params_parse
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Jack error: Unable to create JACK client
jack_client_close called with a NULL client

Server not booted.
<pyolib.server.Server object at 0x1671150>
```

None of the solutions to any of the error messages i managed to find on google changed this error message. ([google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Jack%20error%3A%20Unable%20to%20create%20JACK%20client&rlz=1CAASUF_enUS671GB671&oq=Jack%20error%3A%20Unable%20to%20create%20JACK%20client&aqs=chrome..69i57.410j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) googled other, but you don't care about my messy internet history)

---

pulseaudio:

---

```
>pulseaudio --start

E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
```

Could this be the main problem as Precise and the ChromeOS are running sidebyside and this causes a lock on the Deamon?

---

```
>pulseaudio --kill

E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process
```

---

```
>sudo pulseaudio --kill

E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Home directory /home/USERNAME not ours. 
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: Permission denied
```

sudo permission denied??? PulseAudio running in ChromeOS???

---

jackd:

---

```
>jack_control start

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jack_control", line 399, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/jack_control", line 158, in main
    bus = dbus.SessionBus()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/_dbus.py", line 211, in __new__ 
    mainloop=mainloop)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/_dbus.py", line 100, in __new__
    bus = BusConnection.__new__(subclass, bus_type, mainloop=mainloop)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 122, in __new__
    bus = cls._new_for_bus(address_or_type, mainloop=mainloop)
  dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
```

This just doesn't work cause i "don't have a display" for Jackd to open up in right?

Answer (score 1):

[Solution 1](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/826#issuecomment-43496827): Connecting JACK to CRAS instead of ALSA, probably what you want unless you want to disconnect ChromeOS from audio (open link from solution 2 for more information)

[Solution 2](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Access-audio-hardware-directly-(ALSA,-JACK)): Connecting ALSA and JACK directly to hardware by turning off CRAS